# Adjustwidth of all sections

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, adjustwidth

Is there any way to `adjustwidth` of all sections without writing all the time `adjustwidth`? For example `\begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}` is repeated twice:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\section{Hello}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}
\lipsum
\end{adjustwidth}

\section{Hello2}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}
    \lipsum
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is your aim with that? Wouldn't it be easier to simply adjust the margins and let the section number protrude into the margin?

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible workarounds is to change the margins of the whole document and redefine the `\section{}` so that margins around sections are adjusted. At least that would be a start point:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Only to show a page frame
\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}


% Redefine section
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand\section[1]{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.3cm}{}
        \item
        \oldsection{#1}
    \end{adjustwidth}
}

% Set block margins
\changetext{}{-1.3cm}{}{1.3cm}{}


\begin{document}

% \vspace*{-4em}
\section{Hello}
\lipsum[1][1-7]

\section{Hello2}
\lipsum[2][1-7]

\section{Hello3}
\lipsum[3][1-7]

\end{document}
```

You would have to adjust the vertical space of the first section, though, e.g. by adding `\vspace*{-4em}`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\newcommand{\adjustedwidthsection}[2] {\begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}#2\end{adjustwidth}}`

So your code would become:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\adjustedwidthblock}[1] {\begin{adjustwidth}{1.3cm}{}#1\end{adjustwidth}}``

\begin{document}


\adjustedwidthsection{Hello}{\lipsum}

\adjustedwidthsection{Hello2}{\lipsum}

\end{document}
```

I believe this was the kind of simplification you were looking for.